# How can I use CURL for a put request?

Tags: php, curl, command-line, slim

Ok so Im trying to test my `SLIM` PUT request that essentially updates a row in the database according to the `ID`. Im currently testing curl commands via terminal on my computer before I can actually use them with user inputted data.

I've tried a million different CURL commands. e.g ->

```
curl -i -X PUT -d 'title=James is awesome!&date=2009-03-02' http://localhost/diploma/cloud_computing/ex4/article/1
curl -X PUT -d Title='Test' -d date='02-05-02' http://localhost/diploma/cloud_computing/ex4/article/1
curl -X PUT -d Title=Test -d date=02-05-02 http://localhost/diploma/cloud_computing/ex4/article/1
```

Here's my code (PHP + SLIM):

```
//Update the table. Pass is an ID primary key
$app->put(
    '/article/:id',
    function ($id) {
        if(isset($_PUT['title'])){
            $title = $_PUT['title'];
        }
        if(isset($_PUT['date'])){
            $date = $_PUT['date'];
        }

        $sqlStr = "UPDATE articles SET title = '$title', date = '$date' WHERE id = $id";
        try {
            //Use our getConnection function 
            $db = getConnection(); 
            $stmt=$db->prepare($sql); 
            $stmt->execute();

            //Close the db connection
            $db = null;
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: Do you get any errors? If yes, which ones?

Comment: @DavidePastore - I got no errors oddly enough!

Comment: Do you simply get a blank page?

Comment: @DavidePastore - Probably one of the dumbest, yet most common mistakes, the variable inside the `prepare()` was different to the one that actually held the sql statement (`sqlStr`).  Haha